# Android: How to implement "distributed control"

Tags: android, design-patterns

*{Apologies for the cross-post with android-developers forum. Haven't received any answers there}*

I have an interesting design challenge:

I have a frontend(Activity) and a backend (written in native C/C++)
code. The backend is a complex object which partially controls the
flow of application & once started runs in it's own thread. So I have
a "distributed control" scenario.

The **Activity needs to be able to send messages asynchronously** to the
backend which then takes certain actions. But the **backend also needs
to be able to send messages asynchronously** to the Activity, to which
it responds by chnaging UI, firing methods etc.

Essentially what I need is a two-way listener.

So backend sends a message to screen (take picture, prompt user, get
location, take another picture now etc) and screen does what it needs
to do. But in addition, the screen should also be able to call the
backend-listener to send back messages (captured camera image, system
generated - "I got paused/destroyed" message, etc) in the callbacks of
these events. Main problem is that this is all asynchronous.

Is this possible without tight-coupling? Is this even possible?

I have thought of Asynctask/handlers (but that's a one way street for
informing the UI thread), observer-pattern (both objects will be
observer/observable?) but confused on where to begin. Any thoughts,
links would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have any potential solutions now?  If not and if nobody else replies, I can give you a worst-case scenario solution.

Comment: No potential solutions :-( . Please do give your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your native code, you can use JNI to obtain classes (and objects) from your VM, and once you've got a class (or object) you can locate methods and call them (static methods for a class, all methods for an object). It seems to me that the simple solution is to provide a helper in your java class which encapsulates the native methods and have the native code call into it.

In the past, I've needed to have native code determine if its thread has been interrupted at the Java level. Java provides java.lang.Thread.currentThread() as a static to find your own thread, and java.lang.Thread.isInterrupted() to [non-destructively] determine the interrupted status. I used the following to solve this problem at the native level; perhaps you can use it towards your needs (with appropriate adaptation to message sending, of course):

```
/* JavaThread: this class is a simple wrapper to be used around    */
/* JNI's Thread class. It locates the provided functions as needed */
/* and when it is destroyed (such as going out of scope) it will   */
/* release its local references.                                   */
class JavaThread
{
public:
    JavaThread(JNIEnv *env)
    {
        mEnv = env;

        /* find the Java Thread class within the JVM: */
        mThread = mEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");

        /* find the Thread.currentThread() method within the JVM: */
        mCurrentThreadMID = mEnv->GetStaticMethodID(mThread, "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;");

        /* find the current thread's isInterrupted() method: */
        mIsInterruptedMID = mEnv->GetMethodID(mThread, "isInterrupted", "()Z");
    }
    ~JavaThread()
    {
        if (mThread)
        {
            mEnv->DeleteLocalRef(mThread);
            mThread = 0;
        }
    }

    bool isInterrupted() {
        bool bResult;
        if (!mThread)           return false;
        if (!mIsInterruptedMID) return false;

        /* find the current thread (from the JVM's perspective): */
        jobject jCurrentThread = (jobject)mEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(mThread, mCurrentThreadMID);
        if (NULL == jCurrentThread) return false;

        /* see if the current thread is interrupted */
        bResult = (bool)mEnv->CallBooleanMethod(jCurrentThread, mIsInterruptedMID);

        /* delete the current thread reference */
        mEnv->DeleteLocalRef(jCurrentThread);

        /* and return the result */
        return bResult;
    }

private:
    JNIEnv    *mEnv;
    jclass     mThread;
    jmethodID  mCurrentThreadMID;
    jmethodID  mIsInterruptedMID;
};
```

Instantiation is based on the JNIEnv * provided to your native method, and a simple allocate/call/deallocate line of code to call the isInterrupted() method is:

```
if (JavaThread(env).isInterrupted()) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 for providing info about checking thread interruption from JNI. I knew about the Java part but not the other. However, my main problem is not really about keeping track of each others threads. It pertains to two objects listening to each other's callback & how to implement it.

Comment: @OceanBlue -- yes, of course. I'm hoping that you can use my (working production) code as an example to show how you can access _something_ in Java from native code. Once you know how to do that, it should not be difficult to provide your own methods in your own class to solve the problem, with the native code calling your Java methods as needed. For example, at the native level you could spin up a new thread that calls into a blocking Java method that you provide, and that method would unblock when the appropriate message is received.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying. I was implementing the whole "how to access Java method from native" by implementing a listener interface in the activity. I then passed a reference to "this" to the backend. The native just called the listener's method to get it to do what it wanted. That avoided having a "blocking java code".

Comment: Going back to the original question though, forget about the whole native thing, even if there are two java classes with methods running in two threads. Can they *BOTH* implement listeners, hold a reference to each other & call each other's listening methods? Sounds ghastly coupling-wise. So how to do it??

Answer (score 0):

How about using a blocking queue, because your description reminds me of a the classic producer-consumer problem from parallel programming class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Also Java 1.5 seems to have an implementation of the blocking-queue, I can't recall off the top of my head if its available on Android.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

I'd imagine you can setup 2 uni-directional blocking queue's for communication each way. Q1 would have front-end as producer and back-end as consumer. Q2 would have front-end as consumer and back-end as producer.

Also you could use the "Command" design pattern for the communication 'messages'.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing the links. I'll look more into blocking queues & command pattern if it solves my problem...