# JNI and cancelling AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask, and inside doInBackground() I call C function, which executes for some time. When I cancel my AsyncTask by calling *cancel(true)*, it returns *true* - like task was terminated, however I still see log statements from C code after "termination".

For me it seems that C function is not really terminated.

My question is - how to terminate executing of C function correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142351/android-how-to-implement-distributed-control/6142541#6142541).

Here is C version:

```
jclass thread = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Thread");
jmethodID mCurThread = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, thread, "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;");
jmethodID mIsInterrupted = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, thread, "isInterrupted", "()Z");
jobject curThread = (jobject)(*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, thread, mCurThread);

for (;;) {
    // do some stuff
    jboolean res = (jboolean)(*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, curThread, mIsInterrupted);
    if (res == JNI_TRUE) {
        LOGI("INTERRUPTED");
    } else {
        LOGI("WORKING");
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to call `(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,..)` for `curThread` and `thread` afterwards, or you will see memory leak that PSS is growing continously.

Answer (score 1):

When the AsyncTask is terminated the thread that is running your C function is interrupted. You need to pay attention to the interrupt state in your long-running C code (check isInterrupted?) and exit manually.

**Edit:**

Check out [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) (ffmpeg JNI wrapper), especially `csrc/com/xuggle/ferry/JNIHelper.cpp` for a complete and nicely implemented solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of calling isInterrupted?